# Possibilities for local storage using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have been doing some research on several frameworks that offer creation of platform independent apps. Preferably web based. Xamarin, JQuery mobile, PhoneGap and Apache Cordova are the ones of interest at this point.

The biggest interest has fallen on Xamarin (Since they are created using C#/Visual studio). BUT, the issue is that it seems that since xamarin creates native apps, it does not really work well with html5? 
I found this post: [What is the difference between html5 and xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408992/what-is-the-difference-between-html5-and-xamarin)
But I did not get the answer I am looking for. It seems that it is possible to use html5 with Xamarin, but is this with out too many headachs?

If not, is it possible to create an app (with Xamarin) that will allow working offline if there is no internet connection? What I mean is that I want to be able to save data while working offline, and once I get internet connection, I can upload the data. HTML5 allows this with the localstorage.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xamarin apps can work offline, they are just like native apps.

And just like a native app, you have to decide how to handle the problem of network serialization and local storage.

However, one of the key differences between this and a purely native app is that you have many many more options in terms of how you want to solve that issue.

1. If you know nothing of .Net and all of the fancy stuff it has to offer, then your probably best off using a Xamarin Component from their component store https://components.xamarin.com/. 
   However, things in the component store are often platform specific wrappers (or what Xamarin refers to them "Bindings") of existing native libraries.  So if you're aiming to try and share as much backend and middle-end code as possible, then this *might* not work for your needs.
2. If you have some familiarity with .Net then things can get really interesting.  You can try and find Portable Libraries from Nuget or the Component store, that can be placed into a shared project, that each of your platform specific projects can reference.  http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/
   Shows some of the ways that code can be shared.
3. You can also combine 1. and 2. (if you absolutely have to) using Dependency Injection.  Your shared code project could define interfaces that are then implemented and then constructor or property injected from your platform projects for code sharing goodness.

I'm sure there are more ways, but those happen to be the 3 that I've personally experimented with.  Whenever I think HTML5 I instantly JSON serialization and there are many serializers out there that have been turned into Xamarin Componenents, or that have Nuget Packages.  It really comes down to how you plan on sharing your code, and what frameworks (if any) you plan on using.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin tools produce native apps which can utilize anything platform (operating system) offers and thus filesystem operations. Here you'll need to learn differences between different mobile platforms iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

.net offers serialization which can be used in Xamarin apps, but there are numerous other serialization  libraries like Newtonsoft JSON.net, SharpSerializer and other. To be sure for cross platform portability go for Portable Class Library implementations -  those guarantee that they can be used across iOS, Android and WP (and more).

Then you'll have to learn subtle differences between platforms, like working with Path.Combine(), where is default working folder for platform, adding permissions for external storage, sharing device's filesystem and eventually working with native APIs like IsolatedStorage in WP, or Assets in Android etc...